# Retrieving cookies doesn't work (localhost with custom domain)

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I'm making a little project on my drive and I've stumbled upon a little problem. I've set up custom domain pointed to my directory and wrote some scripts to put cookies (with `setcookie`). So my code for now (setting cookies) is:

```
setcookie('id',$login->id, time()+3600*24);
setcookie('name',$login->name, time()+3600*24);
setcookie('pass',$login->pass, time()+3600*24);
```

So basically - nothing big. Values are taken from database, and inserting cookies works fine. They're there, pinned to my domain. Problem comes when I try to print them. I tried echoing and setting up variable with `$_COOKIE['id']` and using `print_r($_COOKIE)` to see them. Both are returning null values. What can I do?

Comment: Do you maybe have your browser configured to reject cookies? Also, I would not recommend using cookies to store passwords in any manner…

Comment: No, no, I tested it in three different browsers (Chrome, FF and Opera) and it doesn't work on any of these.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Inserting cookies works fine. They're there, printed to my domain."? Also, how are you pointing the domain to your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must consider that the variables in the $ _COOKIE will only be available on the next time page loads.

Secondly, try to specify the domain for cookies.

```
   setcookie('id',$login->id, time()+3600*24,'/','site.com');
   setcookie('name',$login->name, time()+3600*24,'/','site.com');
   setcookie('pass',$login->pass, time()+3600*24,'/','site.com');
```

and last, check the function `setcookie()` return.

```
   var_dump( setcookie('id',$login->id, time()+3600*24,'/','site.com') );
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it works with the domain definied. Can you tell me, why? I mean, it is the first time I needed to define domain (working on localhost and on the 'Net/custom domains).

Comment: I do not know why this is happening, but I faced with such problem before. Then I have not had time to look, but now I can not reproduce it. I think the problem appears because of changes in headers introduced by a Web server. This behavior is contrary to RFC6265. and even deprecated RFC2109.

Comment: Very weird indeed, but nevertheless, your solutions works. Thanks again!